# Empty path/file not found

Tags: c#, resources, text-files

I am having a problem with writing text to a file. This is my code:

```
string[] data = { "[Civilisation Manifest ?.1]", "#Structure: ", "#Gold:" };

string path = Properties.Resources.save;
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, data);
```

And the exception I am having is that `An empty path cannot be used.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the value of path? i guess it's an empty string

Comment: @AcidJunkie i have a `save.txt` file in my Resources folder and path is defined as `string path = Properties.Resources.save;`

Comment: i suggest to debug it ;)

Comment: @AcidJunkie apparently the path always stays empty even if i assign a value to it ... how can i get the path of a resource and properly use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the value of `Properties.Resources.save` is not set.

- Open the Properties of your project.
- Go to tab "Resources"
- Probably there is a resource "save", but no value set for it, like here:

[image]

- Set the value to the path to your save file, for example "C:\temp\mysave.txt".

P.S.: The point of resources mostly is to read data *out* of them, not to write data *into* them. For example, they will be copied to the build result folder or embedded directly into the .dll, so you can't really write to them anyway. For writing out a save file, resources are therefore probably not what you want to use; Just create a new file directly instead. (The path to that file, being a hardcoded string, can be stored as a resource as shown above.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the path variable? The error message implies it is empty. Sorry for stating the obvious.

Path must be full path and folder. c:\temp\myfile.txt for example.

Comment: I have a `save.txt` file in my Resources folder and path is defined as `string path = Properties.Resources.save;`

Comment: Updated answer. Try setting full name including path and file name.